# Sqlite3 возвращает только одно значение

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, sqlite3

*Телеграм бот с рассылкой. Проблема заключаеться в том, что бот присылает рассылку только одному человеку, который первый в базе даных. Консоль ошибок не выдает, что не так, не понимаю.*

**bot.py**

```
"""import"""
import config
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from db import Database

"""logging"""
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

"""bot initialization"""
bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
db = Database('database.db')

"""variables"""
welcome = "Привет!"
succes = "Успешная рассылка!"

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def welcomee(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.type == "private":
        if not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id):
            db.add_user(message.from_user.id)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, welcome)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['sendall'])
async def sendall(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.type == "private":
        if message.from_user.id == 5103322701:
            text = message.text[9:]
            users = db.get_users()
            for row in users:
                try:
                    await bot.send_message(row[0], text)
                    if int(row[1]) != 1:
                        db.set_active(row[0], 1)
                except:
                    db.set_active(row[0], 0)

            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, succes)

"""run long-polling"""
if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

**db.py**

```
import sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchmany(1)
            return bool(len(result))

    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`) VALUES (?)", (user_id,))

    def set_active(self, user_id, active):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE `users` SET `active` = ? WHERE `user_id` = ?", (active, user_id,))

    def get_users(self):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("SELECT `user_id`, `active` FROM `users`").fetchmany()
```

**database.db**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделайте `print(row)` после `for row in users:`

Comment: (1240719760, 1)

Comment: А у вас в бд есть кто-то ещё кроме него? Ибо вы показали только одного юзера в бд

Comment: есть ещё конечно

Comment: сейчас отредачу вопрос

Comment: что-то известно?

Answer (score 0):

Замените `fetchmany` на `fetchall`.
Фишка в том что по-умолчанию в `fetchmany` стоит `1` и оно выдает только одну запись

Comment: а нужно заменить везде или в конкретном месте? Я просто заменил, рассылка работает, это круто конечно, но теперь пользователи не добавляються в базу

Comment: могу ошибку показать

Comment: нет, только в `get_users`

Comment: спасибо, всё работает

Comment: В таком случае закрывайте вопрос нажав на "галочку" слева от ответа